# Пишу простой калькулятор на с++. Нужно чтобы операции шли друг за другом без перезапуска программы, пробовала использовать цикл while

Tags: c++, калькулятор

Дали домашнее задание по программированию на с++, где условием для калькулятора было: Приложение должно иметь возможность производить вычисление за вычислением без необходимости перезапускать программу. Попробовала использовать бесконечный цикл while, в итоге программа не перезапускается, но при этом выводится прошлый результат

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

//нужны операции + - * \ ^
//деления на 0 не должно быть, если пользователь попытается это сделать должна появится ошибка
//нужен бесконечный цикл для безостановочной работы
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");

    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    char op = ' ';
    
    cout << "Пожалуйста, введите переменные" << endl;

    cin >> a >> op >> b;
    cout << endl;
    while ((true))
    {
        if (op == '/' && b == 0)
        {
            cout << "Делить на 0 нельзя! Попробуте ввести другое число!" << endl;
        }
        switch (op)
        {
        case '+':
            cout << "Результат: " << a + b;
            break;

        case '-':
            cout << "Результат: " << a - b;
            break;

        case '/':
            cout << "Результат: " << a / b;
            break;

        case '*':
            cout << "Результат: " << a * b;
            break;

        case '^':
            cout << "Результат: " << pow(a, b);
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Не тот оператор! Пожалуйста введите новый оператор" << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы в самом деле не видите, что вы вводите данные однократно, *за пределами цикла*?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно поместить cin в Ваш цикл while